# Import or export database by user in Flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I used SQFLite to create a database. Now I want the user to be able to import/export their own database to the application

Comment: Okay. So I guess you are using Flutter for a local application, not on the web. What is your problem with what you want to do? What *can* you do already, where are you stuck?

Comment: My problem is that I don’t know how I can allow the user to import/export their database file. Can't find anything on SQFLite documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A SQLite database is **a file** in the file system identified by a path. If relative, this path is relative to the path obtained by getDatabasesPath(), which is the default database directory on Android and the documents directory on iOS.

So, as long as you close all database connections, you should be able to copy this file to somewhere and take an existing file from somewhere and overwrite your database. That is the easiest way to import/export the data completely.

If you want to actually *merge* data on import instead of overwriting, I think you will have to write that logic yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought I should do this through the SQLite itself. sorry I can't vote up for you because it is my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method for controlling a certain database in my application, you can take it and modify it:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
class RoomsDbHelper {
  static final RoomsDbHelper _instance = RoomsDbHelper.internal();
  factory RoomsDbHelper() => _instance;
  RoomsDbHelper.internal();
  static Database _db;
  Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
    print('trying to create 3');

    //define the path to the database
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'rooms.db');
    print('trying to create 5');
    _db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int v) {
      //create all tables
      print('trying to create 6');
      db.execute(
          "create table rooms(id integer , name varchar(50) , roomIcon integer, iconFamily varchar(50), linkIp integer, mID integer, mPass varchar(50),fireSensor integer)");
    });
    return _db;
  }

  Future<int> updateRoomName({String newName, int id}) async {
    Database db = await createDatabase();
    int count = await db.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE rooms SET name = ? WHERE id = ?', ['$newName', '$id']);
    print('here in custom ir asasd 22');

    return count;
  }

  Future deleteAllRooms() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'rooms.db');
    try {
      await deleteDatabase(path);
      print('deleted succesfulyy');
    } catch (e) {
      print('didnt deleteete $e');
    }
  }

  Future<List> allRooms() async {
    Database db = await createDatabase();
    return db.query('rooms');
  }
  Future<List<String>> allNameOfRooms() async {
    Database db = await createDatabase();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
    await db.rawQuery("select name from rooms");
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return maps[i]['name'];
    });
  }
}
```

and whenever you want to use this class just call any of the following or any other function (you can modify the given function to justify your needs):

```
  RoomsDbHelper helper= RoomsDbHelper();
    await helper.createRoom(room);
    await _roomsDbHelper.deleteAllRooms();
```

You will need to modify it for your application.

Comment: How does that help the OP import or export a database?

Comment: Ops!, I thought he just wants to import the data in the database, not the whole database file.