# Flutter how export database or copy database

Tags: flutter, sqlite

In my app i use sqlite and i want to copy database file and paste to another phone
location. In app i have to set database location i use `mydatabase = await openDatabase(join(getDatabasesPath(), "pilots.db"),` getDatabasesPath() and i have to change location but i don;t know how i tried path_provider but i probably do something wrong

here is someting about it
[Import or export database by user in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560621/import-or-export-database-by-user-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/getDatabasesPath.html), the default location is under /data/data inorder to confirm that run your app in an emulator fill in the data then open the Device File Explorer in Android Studio and navigate to the above folder and search for your app's db there.

In case you want to change your DB location check out this [example](https://github.com/yaostyle/Flutter-SQFLite-Example/blob/master/lib/data/database_helper.dart).
From the example:

```
io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = p.join(documentDirectory.path, "main.db");
var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
```

Comment: But probably i won't see app folder because is shared ? i can;t find any app folder in my phone

Comment: Real phone  of course  .